# SQL Server (getutcdate()) inserts default value on external POST

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I recently started diving into SQL Server Management Studio along with Web API 2. I followed a tutorial that instructed that I can get a current date for when a database row is inserted into the table. I used the `getutcdate()` function and when I create a new row inside SQL Server Management Studio, the date fills in automatically like it is supposed to.

However, when submitting a POST from my WebAPI project (using Entity Framework) the date created value populates as this value, 0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000.

Now, I assume that is the default value for the `datetime2(7)` type or something, but I want to know why it won't auto generate the current date time like if I was adding it in SQL Server Management Studio.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Here is my `Post()` method:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] TestPerson person)
{
    try
    {
        using (TestWebAPIEntities entities = new TestWebAPIEntities())
        {
            entities.TestPerson.Add(person);
            entities.SaveChanges();

            var message = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, person);
            message.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri + person.id.ToString());

            return message;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
    }
}
```

Here is the `TestPerson` generated class:

```
public partial class TestPerson
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfKids { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You are passing value from C# (struct with value 0001-01-01) so the default cannot be used. I suggest to intercept query that is sent to db. It should look like: `INSERT INTO tab(col1, timestamp_col) VALUES (..., '0001-01-01 00:00:00.000')`

Comment: Are you using Code First approach with Entity Framework or are you working with an existing database which is not generated by EF?

Comment: @CodeNotFound I am working with an existing test DB that I created in Management Studio.

Comment: @CAlex Can you show us how TestPerson entity look like by editing your question please?

Comment: @CodeNotFound I just updated the post with the TestPerson entity.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda I am not sure how to perform an interception. I am extremely new to EF and MS SQL Server for that matter. I did a quick search and didn't turn up anything useful. Is there any links you can point me towards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said in comments to your question, you're using a database that is created within SSMS which mean you're using database first approach.

You need to follow these steps to make sure that all created rows into `TestPerson` table will have their `CreateDate` column set to the current sql server date time as default value.

#### Modify `TestPerson` table

Tell your database to set `CreatedDate` value to `GETUTCDATE()` when that column is  not provided when new insertion is made for `TestPerson` table. So use this TSQL:

```
ALTER TABLE TestPerson 
   ADD CONSTRAINT DF_CreatedDateValue DEFAULT GETUTCDATE() FOR CreatedDate
```

#### Modify your TestPerson entity class

Tell Entity Framwework that your `CreatedDate` property will be computed (generated) by the database by using `DatabaseGenerated` data annotation attribute like below:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
public DateTime CreateDate { get; private set; }
```

Or by using fluent configuration like below:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TestPerson>().Property(entity => entity .TestCreated) 
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed);
```

#### Testing your Web API

That'all! You can test your Web API. After saving `person` instance to your database you will see that `CreateDate` will be be populated with a default value created by the database.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough response. Using the DatabaseGenerated annotation makes sense and seems to be the piece I was missing. However, even after adding that and recompiling, I still get the same result. I had already set the default value of the CreateDate column in SSMS, but I deleted it and ran the query you provided just in case. It still returns: 0001-01-01T00:00:00 on POST. Just as a side note, the datatype I am using for CreateDate in SSMS is datetime2(7).

Comment: Are you sure you're not intializing the proeprty yourself somewhere. Find all references of that proeprty and make sure you're not setting it.

Comment: I see something. In my PersonDataModel.edmx, CreateDate has (None) set for the Default Value. Is this where my issue is?

Comment: It should be Computed i think.